# Search bar to find rows in several accordions

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion, bulma

I have several HTML tables hided in accordions panel, I need to search into all the tables to find a row, did I miss something to deploy corresponding panel and highlight the corresponding row ?

Here is my code:

```js
function testSearch(){
        console.log("testresearch")
        let input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value
        input=input.toLowerCase();
        let x = document.getElementsByClassName('panel');
          
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
            if (!x[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
                x[i].style.display="none";
            }
            else {
                x[i].style.display="list-item";                 
            }
        }
    
    }
```

```html
<input
    id="searchbar"
    onkeyup="testSearch()"
    type="text"
    name="search"
    placeholder="..."
  /><br />
  <button class="accordion button is-light">A</button>
  <div class="panel" style="">
    <table class="dataframe table is-hoverable is-fullwidth clickable-table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>A</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion button is-light">B</button>
  <div class="panel" style="">
    <table class="dataframe table is-hoverable is-fullwidth clickable-table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>B</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

The result is not what I need, I just have some changes in my HTML structure, but I need my panel to be active, and after I will need to highlight the matching input with correponding rows

Comment: Just wanted to confirm if I understood you correctly. So, You want the input to search the values inside all the accordion tables and then highlight the result for the matched data. Correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//  use this
let x = document.querySelectorAll('td');           //  select all <td> tags
//  instead
let x = document.getElementsByClassName('panel'); //  select first <div class="panel"> tag
```

Below full code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Untitled</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="searchbar" onkeyup="testSearch()" type="text" name="search" placeholder="..." autocomplete=false/><br />
    <button class="accordion button is-light">A</button>
    <div class="panel" style="">
        <table class="dataframe table is-hoverable is-fullwidth clickable-table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion button is-light">B</button>
    <div class="panel" style="">
        <table class="dataframe table is-hoverable is-fullwidth clickable-table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>D</td>
                    <td>E</td>
                    <td>F</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script>
        function testSearch() {
            console.log("testresearch")
            let input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value
            input = input.toLowerCase();
            // let x = document.getElementsByClassName('panel');
            let x = document.querySelectorAll('td');    //  select all <td> tags instead of div.panel tag
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {            //  for loop
                if (!x[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
                    x[i].style.display = "none";
                    x[i].style.background = "white";    //  setting background style to normal color
                }
                else if(input<=0){                      //  if input is empty
                    x[i].style.display = "initial";     //  set style to normal default
                    x[i].style.background = "white";    //  background to normal
                }
                else {                                  //  if input contains value that matches <td> value
                    x[i].style.display = "initial";     //  set style to normal default
                    x[i].style.background = "yellow";   //  set background color to YELLOW as same color of highlighted text
                }
            }

        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```